# Dealloc causing crash in changing between scenes in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, exc-bad-access

I'm building a Cocos2D game in which after two certain sprites collide (by simple bounding box technique), I call

`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameOverScene];`

to change to the game over scene.

Once it initializes the game over scene with everything in it, the game crashes and goes to this method in `ccArray.m` class:

`void ccArrayRemoveAllObjects(ccArray *arr)
{ while( arr->num > 0 )
        CC_ARC_RELEASE(arr->arr[--arr->num]);
}`

with the message:
**Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".**

I tried to debug using breakpoints and figured out that once my gameOver scene gets initialized and ready to display, the `dealloc` method in the previous class (the gameplay class, which called the replace scene) gets called and after which it throws this error.

My `update` method:

`-(void)update:(ccTime)dt
{`

`if (CGRectIntersectsRect(plane.boundingBox, enemy.boundingBox)) {

                CCScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverLayer sceneWithWon:NO];
                [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameOverScene];
            } }`

My `dealloc` method:

`- (void) dealloc
{`

```
[super dealloc];

[_monsters release];
_monsters = nil;
[mole release];
mole = nil;
[text release];
text = nil;
[mBG1 release];
mBG1 = nil;
[mBG2 release];
mBG2 = nil; }
```

I have no clue why this is happening. Please help.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Can you post your dealloc method of the gameplay class or any relevant code for the crash ?

Comment: @giorashc Please see the question again for the code. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling super's dealloc before you are deallocating your gameplay scene.
Call super's dealloc at the end of your dealloc method :

```
- (void) dealloc {   
   [_monsters release];
   _monsters = nil;
   [mole release];
   mole = nil;
   [text release];
   text = nil;
   [mBG1 release];
   mBG1 = nil;
   [mBG2 release];
   mBG2 = nil; 

   [super dealloc];
}
```

When you are calling super's `dealloc` first you are releasing your instance making it members invalid so accessing them after the `dealloc` will create memory bad access issues

Comment: Tried this. But now it crashes on the `[super dealloc]` line.

Comment: I am not sure about this but can you put NSLog in your dealloc method and check how many times this log prints to screen when the bodies collide

Comment: It is called only once, when the sprites collide, it loads the next scene, and after loading it, it calls the dealloc method and crashes on `[super dealloc]`. Please help. I have got no clue how to get this problem fixed

Comment: before trying my answer in what line did it crash ? was it also on [super dealloc]? can you also post the method where you create the gameplay scene and add it as the current scene ?

Answer (score 1):

because you didn't show enough code,i can only guess that some of these objects,such as _monsters,mole,text,mBG1,mBG2,were autoreleased before you release them in the dealloc funtion.So,they can not be released anymore.This is concerned ARC-automaic reference counting which you should know, it's basis of ios.
try this only:

```
- (void) dealloc {

    [super dealloc];

}
```